# Hardware Support for Paging

Tags: operating-system, paging

"The address consists of 16 bits, and the page size is 8KB. The page table thus consists of eight entries that are kept in fast registers."
How do we get the total entries in the page table as 8?

According to the  calculation it should be 1.

Total Entries in the Page Table= ((2^16)/(2^3*2^10*2^3))=1.
(The first 2^3 is for 8 in 8KB, the second one is for bytes to bits conversion and 2^10 is for "Kilo" in 8KB.)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Memory is byte-addressable hence, you do not need to divide by 2^3 for bytes to bit conversion.

Explaining it further, 16-bits for address means that the processor will generate memory addresses of length 16 bits which will be used to address the byte or half-word or word present starting (or ending - depends on the endianess of the machine)  at that 16-bit value.

Now, the page size is the total size of a page in bits which in this case is 2^16 bits. But as memory is byte addressable, hence number of processor addresses in one page will be 2^16/2^3 i.e 2^13 addresses.

Hence number of page table entries are 2^16/2^13 = 8.